# React native onChangeText execute only one function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

I have a weird problem with react native 0.62, in onChangeText, I try to call 2 functions setData and checkEmailSyntax. I don't know why but only the first function executes. I have seen similar questions, but nothing works.

Also, I have this same problem with context. Context returns function like logout, setUser, and so on when I try to execute these functions one after another in useEffect only the last function is called.

Do you think this is a react native version problem? or it is my fault.

Ok, @Nestoro solved this mistary, the checkEmail is coping old state without a new email so the email state is empty. New question is can I mutate a wrongEmailSyntax state? or I have to use a useEffect and fire it every time when email changes?

```
      <TextInput
        style={styles.inputText}
        placeholder="e-mail"
        autoCompleteType="email"
        onChangeText={text => {
          setData({ ...data, input_email: text });
          checkEmailSyntax(text);
        }}
        autoCapitalize="none"
        placeholderTextColor="grey"
      />
```

```js
  const checkEmailSyntax = (inputVal) => {
    if (inputVal.includes('@') && inputVal.includes('.')) {
      setData({ ...data, wrongEmailSyntax: false });
    } else {
      setData({ ...data, wrongEmailSyntax: true });
    }
  };
```

```js
  const [data, setData] = useState({
    input_email: '',
    input_password: '',
    wrongEmailSyntax: false,
  });
```

Comment: Does it throw any errors?

Comment: Nope, only execute the last function

Comment: What does checkEmailSyntax do? Maybe you are just overriding the effects or ignoring the fact that setData is probably an asynchronous state update

Comment: I have updated the question, I am not sure but @Nestoro you can be right the checkEmail is overwrites the email because it copies the state

Comment: its racing state

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In react updating state is asynchronous. If we try to consecutively update the state of two different keys of the same object by referencing the seemingly previously updated state in the following way, we will end up with an incomplete update.

```
const [inputs, setInputs] = useState({
    firstName: "",
    lastName: ""
})

const handleClick = () => {
    setInputs({ ...inputs, firstName: "John" })
    setInputs({ ...inputs, lastName: "Wayne" })
}

>> console.log(inputs)
>> { firstName: "", lastName: "Wayne" }
```

Solution is to **pass a function** which will hold the previous state present before the batched update -

```
setData(prevState => ({ ...prevState, input_email: text }));
...
setData(prevState => ({ ...prevState, wrongEmailSyntax: false }));
```

Comment: Thanks, my savior. I swear to god, I didn't use prevstate in react js and it worked with onchange

Answer (score 0):

in `OnChangeText` call only the `checkEmailSyntax` function.  And inside the if in `checkEmailSyntax` do this

`setData({...data, wrongEmailSyntax: false, input_email: inputVal})`

As A G describe state is async!

The new code

```
 <TextInput
        style={styles.inputText}
        placeholder="e-mail"
        autoCompleteType="email"
        onChangeText={text => {
          checkEmailSyntax(text);
        }}
        autoCapitalize="none"
        placeholderTextColor="grey"
      />
```

```js
 const checkEmailSyntax = (inputVal) => {
    if (inputVal.includes('@') && inputVal.includes('.')) {
      setData({ ...data, wrongEmailSyntax: false, input_email: inputVal});
    } else {
      setData({ ...data, wrongEmailSyntax: true, input_email: inputVal });
    }
  };
```